# How do you save an image from camera in Android Studios Java API Level 30

Tags: java, android

Everything on the Developer page is depricated (MediaScan, GetExternalFiles, GetPublicStorageDir). I've been looking around for weeks and can't find a way to save a captured image to the public directory in the current API (Level 30).

Comment: You can write your files to almost all public directories on external storage. Strange you did not see that it goes.

Answer (score 0):

For Android Optimization reasons you will have to use MediaStore to store images in Public Directory(DCIM), like :

**In Kotlin**

```
val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "Image_Name")
    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)
}

val resolver = applicationContext.contentResolver
val uri: Uri? = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)

resolver.openOutputStream(uri). //Copy InputStream in  it
```